# Windows Store Js App: Show badge only on lockscreen and not on live tile

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create badge for our app on lockscreen in windows store javascript app, but the badge count is coming on live tile's bottom-right corner as well.

Is there any way to show badge on only lockscreen and not on live tile?

Answer (score 0):

No, the lock screen simply reflects the app's most recent tile information (badges and tile text if you're the primary lock screen app), so the lock screen is not considered separate contexts.

I'm curious what your scenario is--the tile and lock screen are tied together like this so there's consistency between lock screen and tiles, so I'm wondering about cases where you'd not want this behavior.